# Change form action attribute on submit

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a form with multiple buttons. I want to change the `action` and `target` property when the button with id `new` is clicked.

Here is my attempt:

```
<div id="root">
    <form :action="form.action" ref="form" :target="form.target">
        <button >Submit to /test</button>
        <button id="new" @click.prevent="submit">Submit to /new</button>
    </form>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#root', 
        data: {
            form: {
                action: '/test',
                target: '_blank'
            }
        },
        methods: { 
            submit: function() {
                this.form = {
                    action: '/new',
                    target: '_self'
                };
                console.log(this.$refs.form);
                this.$refs.form.submit();
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```

However, it seems that the form is always submitting to `/test`, even if click on `#new` button.
Also, `console.log(this.$refs.form);` returns

> <form action="/new" target="_self">

So why is the form not submitted to `/new` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `prevent` thing was the troublemaker.

This works:

```
<div id="root">
    <form :action="form.action" ref="form" :target="form.target">
        <button >Submit to /test</button>
        <button id="new" @click="submit">Submit to /new</button>
    </form>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#root', 
        data: {
            form: {
                action: '/test',
                target: '_blank'
            }
        },
        methods: { 
            submit: function() {
                this.form = {
                    action: '/new',
                    target: '_self'
                };
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```

However, I'm not sure why the old version did not work.